# Showing simulation of the recursion, given the recursion algorithm

Tags: c, recursion

The following program in C takes n as an input and finds the sum of the series up to nth term using recursion. The series is given below:
(1 x 3) + (2 x 5) + (4 x 7) + (8 x 9) + ... + nth term

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int addNumbers(int n);
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter a positive integer n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Sum = %d", addNumbers(n));
    return 0;
}

int addNumbers(int n){
    if (n>0)
        return pow (2, n-1)*(2*n+1)+addNumbers(n-1);
    else
        return n;
}
```

**How can I show the simulation of the recursion for n=5 in my code?**

Comment: Show it in what way? Maybe just add `printf()` calls to the function?

Comment: You need to rewrite the function to be more verbose, e.g. `a=pow(); b=2*n+1; c=addNumbers(); result=a*b+c;` Then you can print whatever you want, before returning the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before returning the `pow(2, n-1)*(2*n+1)+addNumbers(n-1)` operation you can print to get the simulation. Since the recursion is used here top down process so your simulation also effect to top down method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int addNumbers(int n)
{
    if (n>0){
        int a=pow(2,n-1);
        int b=2*n+1;
        if(n>1)
            printf("(%d x %d) + ",a,b);
        else
            printf("(%d x %d)\n",a,b);
        return pow(2, n-1)*(2*n+1)+addNumbers(n-1);

    }
    else
        return n;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a positive integer n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Sum = %d", addNumbers(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter a positive integer n: 5
(16 x 11) + (8 x 9) + (4 x 7) + (2 x 5) + (1 x 3)
Sum = 289
```

If you want to get the bottom to top approach simulation then follow this operation.

```
int sum=0,tmp;
int addNumbers(int n)
{
    if (n>0){
        sum+=pow(2, n-1)*(2*n+1)+addNumbers(n-1);
        int a=pow(2,n-1);
        int b=2*n+1;
        if(tmp==n)
            printf("(%d x %d)\n",a,b);
        else
            printf("(%d x %d)+ ",a,b);
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a positive integer n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    tmp=n;
    printf("Sum = %d\n", addNumbers(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter a positive integer n: 5
(1 x 3)+ (2 x 5)+ (4 x 7)+ (8 x 9)+ (16 x 11)
Sum = 289
```

Comment: Your bottom to top approach simulation, doesn't give 289 as the output when I enter n=5

Comment: Both of the codes giving me the same result 289. Can you please check again? Whereas code logic also same

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to trace the recursion is to insert some `printf` statements.

```
int addNumbers(int n){
    if (n > 0)
    {
        int term = pow(2, n - 1) * (2 * n + 1);  // = (1 << (n - 1)) * (2 * n + 1) 
        int sum = term + addNumbers(n - 1);
        printf("+ %d = %d\n", term, sum);        // +++
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("= %d\n", n);                     // +++
        return n;
    }
}
```

Output with `n = 5`:

```
= 0
+ 3 = 3
+ 10 = 13
+ 28 = 41
+ 72 = 113
+ 176 = 289

Sum = 289
```

You could also get rid of the `pow` call (which is dangerous, expensive and uses floating point unnecessarily) by using a variation of the recursion that calculates the powers as it goes.

```
int addMulNumbers(int n, int *p){
    if (n > 0)
    {
        int mul = addMulNumbers(n - 1, p);
        int term = *p * (2 * n + 1); 
        int sum = term + mul;
        printf("+ %d = %d\n", term, sum);        // +++
        *p *= 2;
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("= %d\n", n);                     // +++
        return n;
    }
}

int addNumbers(int n){
    int p = 1;
    return addMulNumbers(n, &p); 
}
```